# Filled Contour Plots/Isopleths in R

Tags: r, heatmap, contour

I am trying to create a filled contour plot in R illustrating water temperatures throughout a water column over time.  The water temperatures are taken approximately at 1-m intervals, but not always. I can create a filled contour plot with temperatures taken at regular depth intervals but not irregular depth intervals; this plot looks like it ignored the temperatures collected at irregular intervals. Below are my data where the first row in the matrix are depths (y) and first column are the dates (x) the samples were taken (z). Any advice or example code would be appreciated.

Thank you.

```
                 0     1     2     3     3     5     6     7     8     9    10  10.1  10.2  10.5  10.6  10.7    11  11.5
1   6/5/2015 14.79 14.81 14.73 14.73 14.71 14.70 14.71 14.70 14.70 14.70 14.70    NA    NA 14.70    NA    NA    NA    NA
2  6/10/2015 17.40 17.40 17.39 17.38 17.40 17.41 17.42 17.39 17.40 17.41 17.42    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
3  6/18/2015 17.79 17.75 17.75 17.75 17.74 17.75 17.74 17.74 17.74 17.74 17.74    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
4  6/29/2015 17.38 17.39 17.40 17.40 17.38 17.34 17.34 17.33 17.33 17.32 17.32    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
5   7/7/2015 20.66 20.59 20.56 20.43 20.05 20.04 20.04 20.04 20.04 20.04 20.03    NA 20.04    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
6  7/15/2015 24.16 24.16 24.14 24.12 24.12 24.12 24.12 24.13 24.14 24.14 24.14    NA    NA 24.14    NA    NA    NA    NA
7  7/23/2015 22.15 21.97 21.80 21.82 21.79 21.81 21.81 21.82 21.82 21.82 21.83 21.83    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
8  7/29/2015 25.45 24.73 23.87 23.84 23.84 23.85 23.85 23.85 23.85 23.84 23.84    NA 23.84    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
9   8/5/2015 25.19 25.04 24.40 24.35 24.33 24.30 24.24 24.23 24.21 24.18 24.17    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
10 8/12/2015 24.01 23.88 23.68 23.58 23.53 23.52 23.52 23.54 23.57 23.60 23.58    NA    NA    NA    NA 23.63    NA    NA
11 8/19/2015 25.25 25.06 25.01 24.99 24.91 24.91 24.91 24.91 24.91 24.91 24.91    NA    NA    NA 24.91    NA    NA    NA
12 8/28/2015 25.30 24.96 24.37 24.32 24.29 24.27 24.25 24.24 24.23 24.23 24.23    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA 24.23 24.23
13  9/9/2015 25.36 25.19 24.97 24.79 24.71 24.67 24.63 24.62 24.62 24.61 24.60    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA 24.60    NA
```

Comment: Providing the results of your data frame through `dput()` is easier to input into R.  Also, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to create a filled contour plot using the `filled.contour()` function in base R.  The resulting contour plot is limited not by the irregular intervals, but by the lack of data at depths greater than 10.

```
mat <- structure(c(14.79, 17.4, 17.79, 17.38, 20.66, 24.16, 22.15, 25.45, 
  25.19, 24.01, 25.25, 25.3, 25.36, 14.81, 17.4, 17.75, 17.39, 
  20.59, 24.16, 21.97, 24.73, 25.04, 23.88, 25.06, 24.96, 25.19, 
  14.73, 17.39, 17.75, 17.4, 20.56, 24.14, 21.8, 23.87, 24.4, 23.68, 
  25.01, 24.37, 24.97, 14.73, 17.38, 17.75, 17.4, 20.43, 24.12, 
  21.82, 23.84, 24.35, 23.58, 24.99, 24.32, 24.79, 14.71, 17.4, 
  17.74, 17.38, 20.05, 24.12, 21.79, 23.84, 24.33, 23.53, 24.91, 
  24.29, 24.71, 14.7, 17.41, 17.75, 17.34, 20.04, 24.12, 21.81, 
  23.85, 24.3, 23.52, 24.91, 24.27, 24.67, 14.71, 17.42, 17.74, 
  17.34, 20.04, 24.12, 21.81, 23.85, 24.24, 23.52, 24.91, 24.25, 
  24.63, 14.7, 17.39, 17.74, 17.33, 20.04, 24.13, 21.82, 23.85, 
  24.23, 23.54, 24.91, 24.24, 24.62, 14.7, 17.4, 17.74, 17.33, 
  20.04, 24.14, 21.82, 23.85, 24.21, 23.57, 24.91, 24.23, 24.62, 
  14.7, 17.41, 17.74, 17.32, 20.04, 24.14, 21.82, 23.84, 24.18, 
  23.6, 24.91, 24.23, 24.61, 14.7, 17.42, 17.74, 17.32, 20.03, 
  24.14, 21.83, 23.84, 24.17, 23.58, 24.91, 24.23, 24.6, NA, NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, 21.83, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
  20.04, NA, NA, 23.84, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 14.7, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
  24.14, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, 24.91, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
  23.63, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
  24.23, 24.6, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 24.23, 
  NA), .Dim = c(13L, 18L), .Dimnames = list(c("6/5/2015", "6/10/2015", 
  "6/18/2015", "6/29/2015", "7/7/2015", "7/15/2015", "7/23/2015", 
  "7/29/2015", "8/5/2015", "8/12/2015", "8/19/2015", "8/28/2015", 
  "9/9/2015"), c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", 
  "10", "10.1", "10.2", "10.5", "10.6", "10.7", "11", "11.5")))

dates <- as.Date(dimnames(mat)[[1]], "%m/%d/%Y")
depths <- as.numeric(dimnames(mat)[[2]])

filled.contour(x=dates, y=depths, z=mat, xlab="Date", ylab="Depth")
```

[image: filled.contour]